# Rails checking request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a case in which a Rails request parameter can have multiple values.
e.g. `p1[]=v1&p1[]=v2&p1[]=v3`
However in certain cases it might have just one value:
e.g. `p1=v1`
If in controller I want to check if the parameter p1 is having just a single value 'v1', how can I accomplish that ?

```
if params[:p1] == 'v1'
```

or

```
if params[:p1] == ['v1']
```

or is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: I don't think you can get all the values. Probably, `p1` will only have the last value. It looks like code smell. You should use different keys.

Comment: Edited the question so that p1 can have all the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send params this way, only the last value will be stored in params. You need to explicitly say they are an array:

```
p1[]=v1&p1[]=v2&p1[]=v3
```

Then you can do:

```
params[:p1].include? 'v1'
```

Regardless of how many `p1`s are passed, assuming you always pass `p1[]=` instead of `p1=`. Otherwise, you can always do:

```
Array.wrap(params[:p1]).include? 'v1'
```

### Update:

To check if `v1` is the only value do:

```
Array.wrap(params[:p1]).uniq == ['v1']
```

Comment: Have edited the question to reflect that p1 can indeed have multiple values. Also, I dont want to just check if p1 is having one of the value as 'v1', I want to check if p1 is having only the value 'v1'. Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

using Array include?

```
if ['v1', 'v1v2', 'v1v2v3'].include?(params[:p1])
```

Comment: Just read your answer from OP's point of view and a third person point of view. Then post it, You will never receive such criticism. I was also on the receiving end, but I guess I learnt quickly. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can convert parameter to array if it is a single value, then treat it as normal array all over your code.

```
params[:p1] = [params[:p1]] unless params[:p1].is_a? Array
```

then use params as usual

```
if params[:p1].include? 'v1'
    # do your logic here
end
```